# what is the time complexity for binary division by repeated subtraction?

Tags: asymptotics, runtime-analysis

The divisor and dividend are of length n and m bits respectively.

According to Wikipedia article,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output-sensitive_algorithm
division by substraction is an output sensitive algorithm and has the time complexity of Θ(Q). Can the time complexity be calculated in terms of length of input bits?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? It seems you already have enough information to answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you calculate Z = floor (X / Y) by repeated subtraction, then you will perform Z subtractions. If you divide exactly n bits by exactly m bits, then there are at least $1/2 \cdot 2^{n-m}$ and at most $2 \cdot 2^{n-m}$ subtractions, so it's $\theta (2^{n-m})$ subtractions.

If you divide at most 2 bits by at most m bits, then Y might be 1 and in the worst case there are almost $2^n$ subtractions, so $O(2^n)$ subtractions.